# Get Attribute Option Position from Option value

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, attribute-options

I have a dropdown attribute with many options.

In `cart.phtml` I already get the attribute value for each item

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId())->getMyAttribute();
```

In addition to that I want to get the option position.

How can I do that without loading all Attribute options.

Comment: So, you start a bounty, people waste their time to help, and then you don't even validate the answers... Not fair, man

Comment: Sorry, I'll do it now :)

Comment: Nice ;) Regards, man

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have `$optionId` ( that's the value you get when calling `$product->getData('your_attribute')` ), you can get the **position** (`sort_order`) this way

```
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setIdFilter($optionId);
```

This will return a simple object, something like...

```
Array
(
    [option_id] => 624
    [attribute_id] => 298
    [sort_order] => 0
)
```

Check **Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection** for more details

Comment: sorry I have tried it and it don't work ! :(

Answer (score 2):

Raul was almost correct, but his answer returns a collection, not a simple object. For a specific attribute option it would be:

```
$option = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
          ->setIdFilter($attrOptionId)
          ->getFirstItem();
```

Or to get the sort order (position) of the option directly:

```
$position = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setIdFilter($attrOptionId)
            ->getFirstItem()
            ->getSortOrder();
```

Comment: Thumbs up for you ;)